# How to print dictionary of lists of strings

Tags: python, dictionary, printing

I have a dictionary of dictionaries of lists of ints. I want to loop through each dictionary and produce a table with y-axis being set to list name and x-axis to arbitrary names.

```
a = {'john': {'alex': [5, 6], 'bono': [0, 4]}, 'jane': {'alex': [0, 1], 'bono': [0, 1]}}

for k, v in a.items():
    print('\n' + k)
    for k, v in v.items():
        print(k, v)
```

Current output is:

```
john
alex [5, 6]
bono [0, 4]

jane
alex [0, 1]
bono [0, 1]
```

My desired output is:

```
john   col1 col2
alex   5    6
bono   0    4

jane | col1 col2
-----------------
alex | 0    1
bono | 0    1
```

The number of columns (col1 and col2) is fixed. (The effects in Jane table are optional, can live without it!).

**Edit: I am looking for a non-pandas (import module) solution.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

I've left the pandas code below in case you want to reference it.
Otherwise here is a script with string formatting to print the tables you're asking for. You can try playing around with the numbers to get the script to fit longer names as in this example:

```
# your original data:
outer_name_dictionary = {'john': {'alexis': [5, 6], 'bonofide': [0, 4]}, 'jane doe': {'alex': [0, 1], 'bono': [0, 1]}}

# iterate over each outer dictionary:
for key, value in outer_name_dictionary.items():

    # get inner dictionary:
    inner_name_dictionary = value

    # print the column headers, you can change the '10' to a larger number ...
    # but do the same with the print function below:
    print('%10s | col0  col1' %key)
    print(' '*6 + '-'*18)

    # iterate over ech inner dictionary:
    for inner_key, inner_value in inner_name_dictionary.items():

        # print the column values:
        print('%10s | %4d  %4d' %(inner_key, inner_value[0], inner_value[1]))

    print()
```

Output:

```
      john | col0  col1
      ------------------
    alexis |    5     6
  bonofide |    0     4

  jane doe | col0  col1
      ------------------
      alex |    0     1
      bono |    0     1
```

Pandas solution:

```
import pandas as pd

# your original data:
name_dictionary = {'john': {'alex': [5, 6], 'bono': [0, 4]}, 'jane': {'alex': [0, 1], 'bono': [0, 1]}}

# iterate over each inner dictionary:
for name in name_dictionary:

    # convert each inner dictionary to a dataframe:
    name_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(name_dictionary[name])

    # transpose dataframe:
    name_dataframe = name_dataframe.T

    # assign original name to name of columns in dataframe:
    name_dataframe.columns.name = name

    # rename columns:
    name_dataframe = name_dataframe.rename(columns={
            0 : 'col0',
            1 : 'col1',
    })

    # print results:
    print(name_dataframe)
    print()
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I am looking for non-panda solution (edited description). Will accept your answer if nothing alternative appears.

Comment: If you want to add a (not requested) pandas solution, you should consider `df = pd.DataFrame(name_dictionary);

print(df.T.stack().apply(pd.Series))`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you were pretty close. All you're missing is the column headers and to unpack each list:

```py
for head, d in a.items():
    print(head, "col1", "col2", sep='\t')
    for name, lst in d.items():
        print(name, *lst, sep='\t')
```

This gives on your example dictionary:

```
john    col1    col2
alex    5   6
bono    0   4
jane    col1    col2
alex    0   1
bono    0   1
```

---

For neater alignment you can play with f-strings:

```py
cell_size = 6
for head, d in a.items():
    print(f"{head:{cell_size}} {'col1':{cell_size}} {'col2':{cell_size}}")
    for name, lst in d.items():
        print(f"{name:{cell_size}} {lst[0]:<{cell_size}} {lst[1]:<{cell_size}}", end='')
```

Which now gives:

```
john   col1   col2  
alex   5      6      
bono   0      4      
jane   col1   col2  
alex   0      1      
bono   0      1
```